# The reason why some questions get massive amount of upvotes and other not so much?

Tags: bug, voting

I have seen that many question get a bunch of upvotes after a start,there are many questions which remain unnoticed for several time and once it get some upvotes its popularity start increasing.
Doesn't that indicate that most of the people upvote a question because it is upvoted by others.
Shouldn't this thing be stopped,that is the reason some exellent questions remain unnoticed.
Hope my message reach to those who are responsible for this.
thanks.

Comment: There are actually two issues involved here: the dynamics of voting on the site, and the [Hot Network Questions  sidebar (HNQ)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-questions). There has been a lot of debate about the first question going back to the very beginning of Stack Overflow, but [the data don't really support the idea that there is anything insidious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225034/2509) going on there. What effect the HNQ may or may not have has also been treated, but the whole point of the sidebar is to being in more views (and thus more votes).

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: A downvote most likely indicates disagreement with the idea that "*this thing [should] be stopped*"

Comment: I'd like to point out that your logic is only slightly flawed. The fact that more frequent upvotes are acquired only once the post has gotten a few upvotes and gained popularity does not indicate that people are only voting up because others did. It indicates both that *and* that more people are seeing the question because of its increased popularity. Much of those upvotes come about from people who would vote it up anyway but otherwise would not have looked at the question

Comment: shouldn't  be there a solution,(if you consider it as a problem))??

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra, I recommend that, even if you found enough here that agree that it is a problem worth attending to, you consider the law of [unintended consequences.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences)

Comment: @Alfred century,i agree hope this message reaches community